# Debugging a MySqlDataReader error in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

My project have two libraries once composed by form and the other composed by classes. I try check data from my base using a generic. When I start the program I get an error saying that my connection to my MySql database isn't open or isn't valid.

```
public class DAO {  class for connection to the data base

    public DAO()
    {
    }
 }
```

This class represents a table in my database

```
public class Lot {
   public List<Lot> getAllLot(string query) {
        dao.getConnection() ;         

        // Créer une liste pour stockerle résultat
        List<Lot> list = new List<Lot> () ;

        // ouvre la connection 
        if (dao.openConnection()== true) {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=pharmacie;uid=root;pwd=sqlServer12;");

            // créer la commande 
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand (query, connection);

            // Créer un data reader et executer la commande
            dao.getConnection() ;

            // *** The error is "Connection must be valid and open." 
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // I get error here 

            // lis les données et les stock dans la liste
            while (reader.Read()) {
                list.Add(new Lot 
                             {
                                 numLot = reader.GetString (0),
                                 dateFabrication = reader.GetDateTime(1), 
                                 dateLivraison  = reader.GetDateTime(2), 
                                 datePeremption  = reader.GetDateTime(3)
                             });
            }

            reader.Close();
            dao.closeConnection();
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: you create `MySqlCommand` with `connection` object, you must open connection before `cmd.ExecuteReader();` like : `connection.Open();`

Answer (score 0):

before you assign he connection to the command you need to open the connection by using connection.Open();